# After 15.10 -> 16.04, desktop-file-utils can't be configured

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

Yesterday's x86_64 upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 appeared to go well, but I'm left with this situation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall desktop-file-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libgdata-common libgdata22 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common liboauth0
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,564 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for desktop-file-utils:amd64
$
```

Nothing much is on the system so I'm tempted to do a reinstall, but if an easier solution exists that would be great.  Googling around hasn't helped me solve this.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error, but with a different package name.

First, it looks like you have some partially installed / configured packages in the way. Run dpkg --configure -a to try to resolve those issues. Watch the package names listed if any errors occur. You'll need to remove those and re-install them completely once you're done with your target package.

What helped me was to purge the offending package, clear the cache, and install it again.

```
    # apt-get purge <partially installed/configured packages>
    # apt-get clean; apt-get update
    # apt-get install <package name(s)>
```

You can also download the individual package, and install via dpkg -i  check http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/

```
    # wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/desktop-file-utils/desktop-file-utils_0.22-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
    # dpkg -i desktop-file-utils_0.22-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, chrismeu.  Looks like we were posting answers at the same time.  You're exactly right that a package had been only partially installed - and was a major pain to remove.  Feels good to have a happy system again!

Answer (score 0):

False alarm.  The problem did indeed exist, but I had added another ppa whose package of interest to me seems to have been the real culprit.  A side effect was the problem I posted.  With that ppa removed, all is well again.